# Change toolbar title when changing screens in kivymd

Tags: kivy, kivymd

My program contains two screens. I wish to change  the toolbar title whenever I change screens.

This is my main.py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar

Window.size = (360,640)

global sm

class DashboardScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DashboardScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class DigitalGoldScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DigitalGoldScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDBoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


# Create the screen manager

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(DashboardScreen(name='screen-dash'))
sm.add_widget(DigitalGoldScreen(name='screen-dgld'))



class MoneyManagerCopiedApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoneyManagerCopiedApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)



    def set_toolbartitle(self, screen):
        self.title = screen
        return self.title

    def get_toolbartitle(self):


        screentitle = self.title
        if screentitle == "screen-dash":
            self.settitle = "Dashboard"
        elif screentitle == "screen-dgld":
            self.settitle = "Digital Gold"
        else:
            pass

        return (self.settitle)


    def build(self):
        pass

print(sm.current)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MoneyManagerCopiedApp().run()
```

Here is my .kv file

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Digital Gold"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "screen-dgld"



            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Dashboard"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "screen-dash"

MDScreen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "dashboard"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]


    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            DashboardScreen:
            DigitalGoldScreen:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer



<DashboardScreen>:
    name: 'screen-dash'


    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "You're in dashboard screen"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen-dgld'


<DigitalGoldScreen>:
    name: 'screen-dgld'
    MDLabel:
        text: "You're in digigold screen"
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen-dash'
```

I found somewhere something related to binding a callback function but I didn't understand that. How do I create such a function and place it inside the toolbar property of MDToolbar in .kv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just include the change in your `on_press` for the `Button` that changes the `Screen`. Like this:

```
<DashboardScreen>:
    name: 'screen-dash'


    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "You're in dashboard screen"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'screen-dgld'
            app.root.ids.toolbar.title = 'Digital Gold'


<DigitalGoldScreen>:
    name: 'screen-dgld'
    MDLabel:
        text: "You're in digigold screen"
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'screen-dash'
            app.root.ids.toolbar.title = 'Dashboard'
```

Comment: Hey this worked but I'm assuming your correction guides the code to look for root widget and then search for toolbar with title property. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also let's say I have a function in my main python script which is not under the app class but some other class, what syntax can get me that function in some other class using the kv file?

Comment: The code `app.root.ids.toolbar.title` works like a chain. Te `app` refers to the instance of `MoneyManagerCopiedApp` that is running. The `root` refers to  the root widget of the `app`, which is an instance of `MDScreen` in your code. The `ids` refer to the dictionary of ids that kivy creates from your `kv` file, specifically, the `ids` created in the `MDScreen` object. The `toolbar` selects the `MDToolbar` instance (it has the `toolbar` id assigned), and the `title` is just the `title` property of that instance of `MDToolbar`.

Comment: You can use similar logic to reference an instance of other widget classes from your `kv`. Then a method of that class is simply referenced with the usual `.method` style.

Comment: Thanks a ton for taking your time out!